# subtract now() with a date in pgsql trigger function

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am stuck in subtracting now() with modified date in pgsql trigger function.
      This is my query,

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigger_cust_order_mst_after_update()
 RETURNS trigger AS
 $BODY$
 declare 
   v_log_max_ldate  timestamp;
   v_time time;
BEGIN
   v_log_max_ldate = (select max(d_Ldate ) from cust_order_log where n_ord_srno = new.n_srno);
   v_time = now() - v_log_max_ldate;
```

when this trigger executes,an error occurs as,

ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type date: "1"

CONTEXT:PL/PgSQL function trigger_cust_order_mst_after_update()

Please help me out from this.

Comment: what is the result of `select max(d_Ldate ) from cust_order_log where n_ord_srno = last_val`?.. and why dont you declare v_time as `interval` instead?..

Comment: Result is 2016-04-20 07:08:44+05:30.I want to subtract this result from now()

Comment: from your answer in table column you have `timestamp with time zone` and decalred `v_log_max_ldate  timestamp;` change it to `v_log_max_ldate  timestamptz;` instead

Comment: Does the error mention in which line there is an error?